# erasing nlohmann::json object during iteration causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, json, segmentation-fault, nlohmann-json

I have a simple database consisting of objects with strings containing unix time as keys and strings containing instructions as values

I want to iterate though the database and erase any object who's key is smaller that current time ( so erase objects with dates before current date)

```
for (auto it = m_jsonData.begin(); it != m_jsonData.end(); it++) {
    if (std::stoi(it.key()) <= (std::time(NULL))) {
    std::cout << "command is behind schedule, removing\n";
    m_jsonData.erase(it);
    } else {
    /*
    */
    }
}
```

this code works fine as long as `m_jsonData.erase(it);` isn't invoked. when it does, in the next iteration `std::stoi(it.key())` causes a segfault, after a bit of playing with it I came to a conclusion that is somehow loses track of what it's actually iterating. Is my conclusion true? If not then what is? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Without knowing the exact type of `m_jsonData` I 'd suspect that `erase(it)` will invalidate the iterators.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ m_jsonData is a basic_json data type as described here [link](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/basic_json/) (internally is a some form of associative container) From what I understand removing elements in a iteration range is a defined behaviour as shown in examples here [link](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/erase/)

Comment: Usually you'll get the next valid iterator back as result from `erase()`, the problem is the `it++` at the next loop iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *extremely* normal for mutating container operations to invalidate iterators. It's one of the first things you should check for.

Documentation for [`nlohnmann::json::erase()`](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/erase/#notes):

> **Notes**

> 1. Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator.

> 2. References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.

That means after this line:

```
m_jsonData.erase(it);
```

the iterator `it` can't be used for anything *including* incrementing it to the next element. It is invalid.

Fortunately, the documentation also points out that the successor to the removed element is returned, so you can just write

```
for (auto it = m_jsonData.begin(); it != m_jsonData.end(); ) {
    if (std::stoi(it.key()) <= (std::time(NULL))) {
        it = m_jsonData.erase(it);
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

---

Note that when I say this is extremely normal, it's because the standard containers often have similar behaviour. See the documentation for examples, but this is something everyone should be aware of:

- [`std::vector::erase` Iterator invalidation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Iterator_invalidation)
- [`std::unordered_map::erase` Iterator invalidation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map#Iterator_invalidation)
- etc.

This is exactly the reason [`std::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) was added in C++20, and previously [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) was provided to suppport the `erase(remove_if(...), end)` idiom, instead of writing fragile mutating loops.

Comment: Yep, that works, thank you very much, turns out learning reading comprehension is a life-long process!

Comment: If `std::vector::erase` was mentioned then it is worth pointing out that C++20 has introduced [std::erease](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) which helps remove items from a vector.

Comment: Good point, I'll add a note.